# Packaging multiple Unity3d games in one apk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unity-game-engine

I have 3 different games developed using Unity3D. I am building my apks in Eclipse. The games are launched by a 4th app which is basically a stripped down web browser. My problem is that users are complaining about having to perform a separate installation for each game after they have installed the base "Game Browser" app, making 4 total installs.

Can anyone suggest an alternative way to deploy these apps as more of a one-time process?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably consider building the 4th app as an interface to other three apps. This would mean a complete rebuild of all your games to apk files. Just add your project scenes and build a major app.